# How do you constrain a foreign key to a child

Tags: mysql, sql, relation, erd

A `parent` entity *requires* *one* `child` entity to be marked. Thus, I've added a field `marked_child_id`.

How would I constrain this field to only accept `id`s of `child` entities of the `parent`?

Comment: The title: `How do you constrain a foreign key to a child`. Also, the final line: `Still, the constraint imlementation, of marker_child_id being a child's id, holds [how is this done]`

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand yet the question. Why do you need the marker entity?

Comment: `Marker is simply working as a - required - "selected child" of a parent.`

Comment: Maybe for you that explanation is self explanatory, but I don't get the point on it

Comment: A parent requires a child to be selected, or *marked*. The marker holds the id of the marked child.

Comment: Why don't you use then a 'not null' constraint in the 'parent_id' of the child table?

Comment: Why do you assume there isn't one?

Comment: Ok... sorry buddy, I can't even imagin what do you want to do. Maybe some example with data can help to understand what do you want to achieve.

Comment: Let me rewrite the question

Comment: Read this.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a circular FK reference. These are tricky because you can't declare a foreign key constraint until after the referenced table is created.

```
CREATE TABLE parent (
  parent_id INT NOT NULL,
  marked_child_id INT,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE child (
  child_id INT NOT NULL,
  parent_id INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (child_id),
  UNIQUE KEY (child_id, parent_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES parent(parent_id)
);
```

The above creates the child -> parent reference, which is expected.

Then you need to add an FK constraint so the marked_child_id references the primary key of the child table:

```
ALTER TABLE parent
  ADD FOREIGN KEY (marked_child_id, parent_id) 
  REFERENCES child(child_id, parent_id);
```

I've made edits to the above to respond to your comments.

- `marked_child_id` may be NULL, so you can create a parent row before you add the child.
- The foreign key for marked_child_id must reference the *combination* of the child's two columns child_id and parent_id. That prevents the parent from choosing a child that doesn't reference it in return.

Comment: What's stopping `marked_child_id` from referencing a ***different*** `parent`'s `child`

Comment: Also, with the circular `NOT NULL`s, wouldn't you have a chicken-egg situation?

Answer (score 0):

Note: This is an answer to the original question before that was edited.

---

Make the ID and parent unique in `child` and reference it in `marker`.

```
CREATE TABLE parent
             (id integer,
              PRIMARY KEY (id));

CREATE TABLE child
             (id integer,
              parent_id integer,
              PRIMARY KEY (id),
              FOREIGN KEY (parent_id)
                          REFERENCES parent
                                     (id),
              UNIQUE (parent_id,
                      id));

CREATE TABLE marker
             (parent_id integer,
              child_id integer,
              PRIMARY KEY (parent_id),
              FOREIGN KEY (parent_id,
                           child_id)
                          REFERENCES child
                                     (parent_id,
                                      id));
```

Comment: I've just simplified the question - quite a bit. Does this answer still hold?

Comment: It tries to answer your actual question. It doesn't claim to answer any other question. If you have another question you should have asked it instead.

Comment: `child_id` isn't being constrained according to `parent_id`

Comment: Yes it is. The foreign key references the parent child relationship therefore it fails if the two aren't related.

Comment: also the primary key should only be parent_id, there's a single marker per parent

Comment: Yeah, I missed that one. But it isn't required for the rest to work so it can be easily removed from the primary key constraint.

Comment: You've provided no explanation for how this "answer" even works.